# How can i find a specific input tag inside a td tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table with 5 rows and four td's that am building dynamically. On one of the tds' have an input tag inside it, how can i find it using Jquery?

My code:

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>number</td>
    <td>date</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="row1" value="" /></td>
    <td>amount</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried this but nothing;

$("#mytable #row1")

Gath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get to the input by simply using `$('#row1')`

Comment: I thought so, but something is not right! even with that it does not work! but if  i create the input tag normally and give an id then use the $("#idname") idom, it works! but for the dynamically created inputs...nothing!

Comment: @gath how are you creating it dynamically?

Comment: Sorry guys, i saw were i was goofing! when building the input tag id dynamically i was not doing it right. Thanks it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

the following should work just fine:

```
$('#row1')
```

an Id is always unique (or supposed to be) so you can target it directly

Answer (score 1):

if your using IDs as selectors then by definition they are unique so just use

```
$("#row1")
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, your ids should be unique. However, I would like to point out that `$('#id1 #id2')` also works fine. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/DUqwd/

Answer (score 0):

I have tested and `$("#mytable #row1")` worked fine. You can use `$("#mytable td input")` as well.